# deciding on docker architecture setup and performance

Tags: docker, lxc, proxmox, devops

I will need to virtualize a jenkins software architecture and I don't know which architcture will be more efficient.

I need :

- a jenkins server
- an opensuse server for c/c++ 64 bits compilation
- an msys2 system for win32 compilation and packaging (windows system)
- an old 32 bits ubuntu 10.04 server for compilation.

my IT department bought a server with 24CPU@2.1ghz and 32Gb RAM

my IT department proposed : a LXC container in proxmox

I don't really understand how it will work, does it mean I will run an hypervisor inside another hypervisor and loose performance ?

- running docker either in a linux VM or directly in the server.
- running it in a linux VM : same problem as proxmox ? directly on the server : ok, but this is a dedicated docker server.
- setup an ESxi VMWare server.

What is the added value ?

From my software developer viewpoint , docker is a fast to setup and easy way. I don't want to depend on IT to setup some images.

Comment: Did they intend to provide you with such a small amount of RAM, or did you ask for such a small amount? You almost certainly will want significantly more than that. At least, does it have a modern CPU or did they go cheap there too? And did you intend to run VMs with an **extremely obsolete** version of Ubuntu? All modern Linux distros, including openSUSE, have mingw32 and mingw64 so there should be no need for msys2 on Linux. On Windows it may make a good way to install those packages though.

Comment: @MichaelHampton This is the memory IT provided :-(. old ubuntu 10.04 will be run to keep status of some old applications needed. There is no intent to change msys2 on windows, some python applications are packaged with it too, but that may be taken in consideration

Comment: Using msys2 on Windows is fine; it's trying to use msys2 on Liinux that would be the pointless bit. As for the rest, I hope you have very good migration plans for the obsolete bits.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes, it is msys2 on windows :-)